# How to check for two words ('goat' and 'sheep') with preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How do I check for two words (example 'sheep' and 'goat') with preg_match in PHP?

Example:

```
if (!preg_match(goat|sheep)) header(' Location: / ');
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it's just two words, in my opinion using a string function, like strpos would be better.

Comment: strpos would work but you would need to run it through a foreach loop to check if either word is present. Otherwise it will only return positive if both are present.

Comment: Why can't you just use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Comment: `if ( strpos($str, 'goat') || strpos($str, 'sheep')) header(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
if (!preg_match('~\b(?:goat|sheep)\b~i', $yourstring)) header('Location: /');
```

more informations [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)